# Location europe-westa-2 is not found or access is unauthorized

Tags: google-compute-engine

Previously, I created an jupyter notebook instance on my project and today I deleted it, but I cant create a new one since its said that location

Answer (score 0):

This [location](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#locations) error is caused because the zone name is incorrect, the region is "europe-west2" and the zone can be defined by a letter "a,b,c".

In this case the zone should be set as "europe-west2-a"

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote wrong about my question, I misspell the zone, yeah, I plan to create a new instance on europe-west2-a, but its said Location europe-west2-a is not found or access is unauthorized.

Comment: It seems that this error is because this zone is not available at the moment for notebooks, you can see the available locations by running the following command on cloudshell:

gcloud beta notebooks locations list